# significant test using scikit-learn's permutation test results in the same p-value for all classifiers

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, significance

I'm trying to find out the significance of the results using scikit-learn's [permutation test](http://lijiancheng0614.github.io/scikit-learn/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_permutation_test_for_classification.html#example-feature-selection-plot-permutation-test-for-classification-py) as in:

```
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(clf.best_estimator_, X_train, Y_train, cv=10, n_jobs=10, n_permutations=100, scoring='accuracy')
```

where the clf.best_estimator is the result of cross-validation.

I use it for several classifiers (several independent clf.best_estimator_) but the p-values for all of them is the same 0.00990099009901.

I have no idea why this happens. The strange thing is that this is the same number that is reported in the linked code in scikit-learn user guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in scikit-learn's issues and the answer was: for most of the good classifiers if the random classifier is better than the trained classifier in 1 test out of 100, this magic number would be the result.

so there's nothing wrong with this magic number.